# Javascript/Jquery - Print array of an object in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have an object like this:

```
    [ {
        "id":75349,
        "sportId":0,
        "groupName":"group1",
        "groupLabel":"group1",
        "date":"2018/01/01",
        "time": {
            "start":"14:30",
            "current":null,
            "state":"3",
            "matchTimestamp":1541329200,
            "delay": {
                "firstHalf": 0, "secondhalf": 5
            }
        }
        ,
        "teams": {
            "host": {
                "id": 920176, "originalId": 902565, "name": "team1", "score": [1]
            }
            ,
            "guest": {
                "id": 920166, "originalId": 44, "name": "team2", "score": [1]
            }
        }
        ,
        "events":[ {
            "id": 743342, "playerName": "player312", "status": 1, "teamId": 920166, "time": 44, "relatedPlayerName": null
        }
        ,
        {
            "id": 743351, "playerName": "player322", "status": 1, "teamId": 920176, "time": 53, "relatedPlayerName": null
        }
        ]
    }
,
{
    "id":75345,
    "sportId":0,
    "groupName":"group2",
    "groupLabel":"group2",
    "date":"2018/01/01",
    "time": {
        "start":"14:45",
        "current":null,
        "state":"3",
        "matchTimestamp":1541330100,
        "delay": {
            "firstHalf": 0, "secondhalf": 10
        }
    }
    ,
    "teams": {
        "host": {
            "id": 920173, "originalId": 901051, "name": "tesm32", "score": [0]
        }
        ,
        "guest": {
            "id": 920168, "originalId": 902250, "name": "team20", "score": [0]
        }
    }
    ,
    "events":[]
}
```

I have few arrays in this object. I want to show every group in a table and then every game inside that group will be shown in another table under group table.

something like this:

```
================================
| group1
================================
| team1 - team2
================================
| team3 - team4
================================
| group2
================================
| team5 - team6
================================
| team7 - team8
================================
```

I tried this code:

```
$.each(var_send, function(index) {
        $("table").append("<tr>");
        $.each(var_send[index], function(key, value) {
            $("table").append("<td>" + value + "</td>");

        });
        $("table").append("</tr>");
    });
```

but the problem is I don't know how access arrays in arrays on this obejct. results of this code shows me [object Object] in table rows after group name.

```
================================
| group1
================================
| [object Object]
================================
| group2
================================
| [object Object]
================================
```

I know it looks complicated, I have retrieve this data from a web-service and I need to show this data in a table with some details (team labels and scores).
(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: You can use `console.log(value);` inside the most inner `each` loop and then check the structure of that object. After this, for example, if `value object` has the property `prop1` you can access it simply using `value.prop1`. You can read [Javascript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more info...

Comment: @D.Smania thats a great answer as it allows him to use that skill in future projects as well...

Answer (score 0):

You are being provided with an array of objects, each element in an array has index[0,1,2,...].

from the attached array sample, to get the group name you would do something like

```
array_name[index]['groupName']
```

To get the team name, you would use

```
array_name[index]['teams']['host']['name'] // for the host team

array_name[index]['teams']['guest']['name'] // for the guest team
```